# Has this "generalized standard deviation" been studied?

Tags: statistics, reference-request

$\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|(x_i-\bar{x})^p|}$

For $p = 1$, the formula yields mean absolute deviation.

For $p = 2$, the formula yields standard deviation.

It also allows for $p >= 3$ or $p\in(0,1)$.

Has it been studied before? If so, what are its properties? If not, why?

Comment: Have you seen $L^p$ spaces before?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space  If not, try reading that link and see if you notice the connection to your question.

Comment: Yes. Variants of it anyhow. Maybe google 'skewness' and 'kurtosis' for a start. (The absolute value signs are not always a good idea.)